# Is there any reason to keep my World of Warcraft retail package?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I'm just tidy up my old stuff. I wonder if I can throw away my WoW retail packages or if I should keep them.

Do I maybe need them for proofing that I'm the owner of the game/extension?

If I'm tempted to install it again I install it online either way.

Comment: Opinion based. However, I say throw away. Well, at least that is what I do when one of my retail games gets released in steam and allows the old serial codes to be activated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you've activated the serial key it is bound to your battle.net account, you don't need it for new extensions or for re-installing the game.

You *may* need it again if you are locked out of your battle.net account, you can generally use such packaging to prove you own the account. However there are generally other ways to prove it so it is not required.

So, yes. You can throw away the packaging.

Comment: You can always take a picture of it before you throw it away if you want to be really really sure.

Comment: I'd like to add that if you lose your password, one of the easiest recoveries is by entering the account codes from packages to the support form. I did this when I got hacked and got my account back by just entering my Vanilla,BC and Wotlk codes. So you can throw the package away but keep the codes.